# Saving/Reading a list of object to/from disk

Tags: c#

I have made some changes to my code.
The method to save to disk is working fine.

```
public void SaveList()
{
   FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"persons.dat", FileMode.Create);
   BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
   formatter.Serialize(stream, myList);
   stream.Close();
}

public void ReadList()
{
   FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"persons.dat", FileMode.Open);
   BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
   List<Person> myList = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as List<Person>;
}
```

I can see that the persons.dat file is being created and the state of the object is being saved to the file.
But the problem lies when try to read. When re-run the program and call the method ReadList() no errors are being shown. Then I call a method to dislay the details of the object stored in the list but the list is empty!!

Comment: Are you sure that no exceptions are thrown in ReadList()? Right now, your code simply ignores exceptions.

Comment: Remove try catch block in order to get exception or modify catch block.

Comment: If your `Person` class is changed since the last time you stored it then you will probably won't get it right from previous stored class and `bf.Deserialize()` will throw an exception. In this case, your exception is caught by your `try` block.

Comment: Current post have been edited to illustrate some changes in the code.

Comment: However problem still persists.

Comment: What happens if you replace `as` with a cast? You should avoid using `as`, because it can mask type errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void ReadList()
{
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"persons.dat", FileMode.Open);
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    myList = (List<Person>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    // Here I was creating a new list.. List<Person> myList = (List<Person>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    stream.Close();
}
```

Problem has been solved with the above method.
This problem was that I was adding the object to a new list and not the list I've created in the class.